# Is question about the style of writing unit on scope?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I have a question about how should scientific unit be written. The author uses the style inconsistently, but since they have science background, I think this inconsistency is actually a typography choice. If it's indeed a question about typography, then I think it's on-topic here.

What do you think? The proposed question is on below

---

In the book *What If?*, the author mostly write the units in full words like *kilometer, atmosphere, megawatt* instead of *km, atm, MW*. However he does use the symbols in the drawings:

[image]

In one line both *mm* and *millimeter* are even used together: 
[image]

This makes me confused because I can't find a reason to not using the SI symbols. I guess the reason is similar to writing numbers in words when doing so doesn't look silly for better reading flow feeling. But in the above example, I can't explain why the first number should use *mm* while the second one should use *millimeter*.

What could be the reason for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is a matter of style in writing prose, I'd say this is a question for the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/). I understand your reasoning that this might be typography, but I disagree with it.

As I understand from the comments, [you have already asked this question on Writer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/25305/when-to-not-using-si-symbols-for-units). I'd like to inform you that double-posting questions across the network is heavily discouraged. Moreover, Writer hasn't deemed it off-topic, so they consider it a good fit for their site.

Not liking the current answers is, imho, a poor reason to take your question elsewhere where it would be a *fringe* on-topic question *at best*.

Comment: huh? I think this does not tie to any specific language, so while this might not be off-topic there, it doesn't attract much interest there

Comment: @Ooker See edit.

Comment: well, if it's a question about writing, then I think it's better suit in [writers.se] than [english.se], right? In fact, [I have asked there](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/25305/11428), but the answers focus on the choice of the author, which somewhat does not convince me since I pretty sure there will always have a reason behind what they do. So I think it's typography.

Comment: ok, so if designers also think that it's a stylistic choice by the author, then I'll accept that.

Comment: Well, at least *this* designer does. I'm only one person, in spite of the diamond next to my name :)

Comment: im pretty sure it was already asked here, as well as TeX

Comment: @Vincent well, in fact I completely agree that I shouldn't double post, or re-posting if I don't like the current answers. It's just that I still feel it should have a reason behind that, as I have said before. I have checked your profile, and many of your answers get heavily upvoted, so your answer has a high probability that it reflects other designers too :D

Comment: @joojaa in TeX too? I have seen many typography questions have been closed as off-topic there. If possible, can you link me to those questions? I cannot find them out